# How to create two CSS transitions in parallel on nested elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to create a simple link with a bootstrap glyphicon. On hover, the `background-color` of the `a` changes as well as the font `color` of the glyphicon.

When trying to add a css `transition` however, the transitions appear one after the other (first the bgcolor and then color of the content) rather than in parallel.

I tried:

```
.alltransition, .alltransition *
{
-webkit-transition:background-color .2s linear, color .2s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color .2s linear, color .2s linear;
-o-transition: background-color .2s linear, color .2s linear;
transition: background-color .2s linear, color .2s linear;
}
```

and

```
.alltransition, .alltransition *
{
-webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
-moz-transition:all .2s linear;
-o-transition: all .2s linear;
transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

**html**

```
<a class="play alltransition" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</a>
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wfcsg6ky/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove `.alltransition *` ?  Or is it your goal that the `<span>` has an own transition?

So your `.alltransition` class looks like this -

```
.alltransition{
    -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0dz84dvs/)

[**Fiddle - span color change**](http://jsfiddle.net/qq156mLb/)

Comment: Doh! So obviously if the transitions are applied to all child elements if the parent has the transition class, then there's no problem! Thanks

Comment: np, I'll add another fiddle, where the span itself changes the color. (in case you need it)